# Why are algebraic tori affine?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Working with the definition that an algebraic torus $T$ is an algebraic group over a general field $k$ which, over $\bar{k}$, is isomorphic to a product of finitely many copies of $\mathbb{G}_m$. So we know that $T \times_{Spec(k)} Spec(\bar{k})$ is isomorphic to $Spec(R)$ for a particular $R.$ I'm not sure how to prove this means $T$ was Spec of something to begin with.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Shaun this is a perfectly natural question for someone who's seeing this sort of thing for the first time. It actually leads to a wonderful field of study - as someone with a fair amount of experience in the field, I think this question is fine as-is.

Comment: If you think it's sufficiently motivated here, I'm happy to defer to your knowledge & expertise, @KReiser; my only concern is that there's no clear attempt by the OP to answer the question.

Comment: The gist is that only affines base change to affines by nice enough morphisms: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2382607/nonaffines-must-base-change-to-nonaffines. But maybe there is some better way to think about it for algebraic groups.

Comment: Since this question is answered in the link provided by @IDC, should we close this question as a duplicate even if it is not precisely the same question as in the link?

Comment: Briefly, the name for the type of problem you're encountering here is "descent" - that is, given a fiber product square $$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X' @>>> X\\
@V{f'}VV @VV{f}V \\
S' @>>> S
\end{CD}$$
where $S'\to S$ is nice (a Galois field extension, faithfully flat, etc), if we know something about $X'$ or $f'$, must the same thing be true of $X$ or $f$? If so, then we say the property in question "descends". One early result in this area is that affine morphisms descend along fpqc coverings, which is given by the result in the linked duplicate.

Comment: @KReiser While this is true, I think that in this particular case there is a simpler answer than what is given by fpqc descent in this case. Namely, as there is a canonical morphism $T\to\mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_T(T))$, which is an isomorphism if and only if $T$ is affine, one is reduced to the following much simpler statement: a morphism of finite type $K$-schemes $X\to Y$ is an isomorphism if and only if $X_{\overline{K}}\to Y_{\overline{K}}$ is.